DHT22 reading bad data
I am trying to take a temperature/humidity reading using a Pico H and a DHT22 sensor. I am following the raspberry pi C examples.
https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-examples/blob/master/gpio/dht_sensor/dht.c
I have a connection from the Pico to a pi using minicom and can see the output but I always get a 'bad data' reading. I have tried multiple dht22 sensors and both with and without the resistor (i.e 3.3v in line with dht22 pin 2)

Is there anything obviously wrong with the wiring here? Or any suggestions on something outside the box I might be doing wrong?
It's not easy to take a decent picture that you can verify the wiring from but here is an angled look at the dht22 connections ( I raised it off the break board slightly so you can see the pins)


Just noticed the negative pin coming out of the dht22 isn't connected. Should be on row 25. I have fixed that but output has not changed.

Hard to tell for sure in the picture, but it looks like the ground wire isn't connected to the DHT22 - did you miss by one row?

Yes. That's what my previous comment was about. I moved it up one row but didn't change the reading.

I think it will be better if you get a DHT22 module instead of the only sensor that you're using.  You can get one from dfrobot: https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1102.html  Your one may be a bad sensor itself. If you cross-check with a QC-passed module, it will be proven if the problem exists in the sensor or somewhere else. For future use, you can make a breakout board like this: https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/i2c___DHT22_Sensor_Breakout_Board_.html

I gave up on the C code completely and tried a python example which worked and proved my Dht22s are fine: randomnerdtutorials.com/raspberry-pi-pico-dht11-dht22-micropython/ using the same wiring and matching the gpio pin i still couldn't get the C code to produce a reading which suggests an issue with the example C code.
